# Navigation with tab bar after login

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a login screen, and I need the navigation and tabbar appear after the login screen.

I tried everything and failed, setting the navigation in appdelegate.me then the tabbar at the login screen.

Comment: Easiest way is to replace the app window's `rootViewController` with your tab bar controller after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your appDelegate.m

```
self.window.rootViewController = your_tabbar_controller;
```

it will inherit to the other class